# Unable to open a specific proposed change in documentation

Tags: bug, documentation

There is currently a proposed change on the Python classes [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/419/classes#t=201607250604095062892).

The link from the review points to this destination: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/26847

However, when I click that link, I get an error: https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/proposed/changes/26847

Another [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/47880) change on Classes works as expected.

Comment: It's been a week, and the bug still there... This probably has chilling effects on people who want to contribute to that topic.